# Is there an option to change output format for `git pull --rebase --verbose`?

Tags: git, git-pull

When I do `git pull --rebase --verbose` I see the line in an output:

```
...
Changes from 4baabb8df936e34958ae4076dccdab6634e4d33b to d404ec36565ad5dd2f476ec7a11f9428e377925d
...
```

Is there an option to show changes in `4baabb8d..d404ec365` format?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, using `git log --abbrev-commit`. Shows only a partial prefix.

Plus, if you use `--oneline`, which is a shorthand for `"--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit"` maybe would be even better.

Here's the doc link: [abbrev-commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/2.21.0#Documentation/git-log.txt---abbrev-commit)